# Upload multiple images to ImageKit through the provided React SDK

Tags: reactjs, imagekit, ikimagekit

We use the **React SDK**, which is provided by **ImageKit**, to upload images directly to ImageKit from the frontend. (The details are not important for this problem.)

It looks like this:

```
<IKUpload
    onError={onError}
    onSuccess={onSuccess}
/>
```

and all is working smoothly as expected.

**BUT** - Now we want the user to be able to select multiple images and also upload them all in one step.

The **PROBLEM** - When adding "multiple" to IKUpload like that:

```
<IKUpload
     onError={onError}
     onSuccess={onSuccess}
     multiple
 />
```

ImageKit **only uploads the first selected image**.

How can we make this work by using the SDK only?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem also, I found that you can't upload multiple files from the client side as stated [here](https://docs.imagekit.io/api-reference/upload-file-api#bulk-file-upload), so the only way to solve this problem is to use server-side uploading.

you can find more about server-side [here](https://docs.imagekit.io/api-reference/api-introduction/sdk#server-side-sdks)